# django formset template loop through fields disables delete featuer

Tags: python, django, formset

Thank you for being here.

I am not able to delete objects in django formset While i am looping through the fields in templates the.

I can see the deletion box but when i hit submit the page refreshes and the object is  exist.

template.html

```
   {%  for form in  request_equipment_form %}
           <div class="card" style="width: 100% ">
    <div class="card-body">

          <div class="d-flex flex-row" style="width:100%">
                              {{form.equipment}}
                              {{form.quantity}}
                              {{form.DELETE}}
                              {{form.ORDER}}
           </div>
                 </div>
```

```
     {% endfor %}
```

But when i do not loop through the fields the delete feature works like charm

```
   {%  for form in  request_equipment_form %}
           <div class="card" style="width: 100% ">
    <div class="card-body">

          <div class="d-flex flex-row" style="width:100%">
                              {{form.as_p}}
           </div>
                 </div>
```

```
     {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
if formset.is_valid():
    instances = formset.save(commit=False)
    for d_obj in formset.deleted_objects:
        d_obj.delete()
    if not instances:
        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    for instance in instances:
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.flight = flight
        instance.station = flight.station
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.save()
            print(instance.date)
            return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you loop through forms in a formset you need to include the the [management form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template) for things to work:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

In your code example incorporate thr management_form like so (assuming that `request_equipment_form` is a formset):

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ request_equipment_form.management_form }}
    {%  for form in  request_equipment_form %}
               <div class="card" style="width: 100% ">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row" style="width:100%">
                                  {{form.as_p}}
                    </div>
               </div>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Also, you should consider using the CSRF token (`{% csrf_token %}`) to secure your form.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).